# Errors in eclipse packages cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I get the below set of errors in eclipse. May I know the reason why they are coming. It says the packages cannot be resolved. I have added all the required external jar files

[image]

Comment: Would recommend you look into Maven. Makes managing dependencies much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi) Download the files,extract and add it into you build path.